# Replace all function calls in Python

Tags: python

I am working with a piece of code that looks like this:

```
# This code is not modifiable

from package import distance as dist

class A:
    def calculate(self):
        ...
        # call to dist()
        ...
```

My code:

```
from package import A

a = A()
a.calculate()
```

As you can see, the `distance()` function is imported at the top of the code. The class `A` makes a call to a `distance()` function. It does so, in several places and not only in `calculate()`.

I want the class to use my custom distance function. However, the class does not let me pass it in the constructor and I cannot modify the code of `A`. How would I do this? Is this possible via subclassing? I tryed the following, which did not work:

```
from package import A

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        from mypackage import mydistance as dist
        return super().__init__()

b = B()
b.calculate()
```

Comment: put another version of `package` earlier in the python path? can you change `package` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, i cannot really change the package. it is from scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: Python is a dynamic language, It's classes, functions and veriables are stored in lookup dicts and can be accessed and modified.
Try doing something like `import package; package.dist = lambda x: 10`
Then try running the code again and see if it was updated

Comment: check the answers bellow ;) I will post the screen shot in a bit. it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) function as follows:

distance.py:

```
def distance():
    print('distance called')
```

mydistance.py:

```
def mydistance():
    print('mydistance called')
```

a.py:

```
from distance import distance as dist


class A:
    def calculate(self):
        dist()
```

main.py:

```
from unittest import mock

from a import A
from mydistance import mydistance


class B(A):
    def calculate(self):
        with mock.patch('a.dist', wraps=mydistance):
            super().calculate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.calculate()
```

Output is:

```
mydistance called
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to put the `with` statement somewhere else (such as in the call site). For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    with mock.patch('a.dist', wraps=mydistance):
        for _ in range(0, 100):
            b.calculate()
```

Patching causes some overhead. Another solution (basically the same as oetoni suggests) is to reassign the attribute (remember to `import a`):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    old_dist = a.dist
    a.dist = mydistance
    for _ in range(0, 100):
        b.calculate()
    a.dist = old_dist
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this immediately from you code without adding new imports or using mock.patch or any third class B. Immediately from yourcode where you are referencing A

Now you just need to do a small change on you code, don't just do `from package import A` but import directly `import baseA` that way we control all the variables in it also the imports ;) and as such we can. Then we can use it's local variable name in order to catch it and change it in runtime :D as such:

Supposed distance() function in import of A

**distance.py**

```
def distance(something):
    return something + 1
```

then I assume the name baseA for the file that contains the class A

**baseA.py**

```
# This code is not modifiable

from distance import distance as dist


class A:
    def calculate(self):
        something = dist(1)
        return something
```

finally youcode file that contains you running code and the place from where we want to modify the dist() that it is imported in baseA

**yourcode.py**

```
import baseA


def newDist(something):
    return something + 2


baseA.dist = newDist
a = baseA.A()


something = a.calculate()
print(something)
```

I successfully managed to change the behavior of dist in baseA as such :)
`baseA.dist = newDist` remember not to put parenthesis because we are passing the function as an object in order to assign its behavior to the **baseA.dist** that is imported from **distance.py** file

testing the solution

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `patch@` decorator in [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).